# How to tell if a solenoid valve is "normally open" or "normally closed"?

Tags: plumbing

I am an electrician, and if I see a relay I can instantly tell by the print on it, whether it is a normally closed or normally open relay. But I have not yet found any way to tell if *solenoid/magnet valves* (the ones that do have a resting position) are normally closed or normally open. I have looked carefully at them. Often they have an arrow, and maybe also a brand name or part number. But I don't see anything that tells me if the solenoid valve is normally open or normally closed.

Is there a way to tell?

**Some power valves have a normal/resting position, but not all**

I'm talking about power operated valves that have exactly one resting position. Like solenoid operated or wax motor operated valves. Every radiator thermostat valve that I have ever seen also had exactly one resting position (which was open).

These valves typically have a pin that is spring loaded outwards, and the when the solenoid is not activated/energized or the solenoid is removed, the pin will go outwards, to the position which is the resting position.

[image]

Some valves are closed in the resting position, some valves are open in the resting position.

Every radiator thermostat valve that I ever worked on was normally open. That means, if you remove the thermostat, the valve will open wide up (allow flow).

Some valves are the opposite. When you remove the actuator, they close.  (block flow).

**Motivation for asking:**

I am trying to understand the heating installation in an old building. The building has a central heating network of pipes, and there are various valves controlled from a central place in one of various ways; some pneumatically, some electrically by either wax motor or solenoid valves.

I have realized that some of the valves are normally open and some are normally closed. So for instance, if the compressor is shut off and the pressure drops in the pneumatic control system, some valves open while others close.

Comment: Can you add some images of the valves in question? It's going to be hard to answer this solely based on your current description.

Comment: The main valve to your house is normally open.  Your sink faucet is normally closed.   The valves themselves don't have any intrinsic 'normal' position.  They are nothing like relays.  The arrow indicates flow direction.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Lets keep this discussion about those valves, that do indeed have a normal/resting position. There are plenty of those, and most of the valves in this building indeed does have a resting position. If power is disconnected or the actuator/solenoid is removed the valve goes into exactly one position, which is the resting position. Even some faucet valves have a resting position, eg https://i.imgur.com/6zGrtd4.png. Its the same for electrical, some switches/relays have a resting position, some don't.

Comment: Are you sure about nc/no or no/no? See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/53219/10902

Comment: Deleted my answer, since the question seems to have changed.